# Include boundary conditions in wave equation solver

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm solving a wave equation using mathematica. I already included the initial displacement and velocity. However, I don't seem to be able to include boundary conditions $u(-\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$.

```
weqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 4*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == (Sin[x])^2}
DSolveValue[{weqn, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
Plot3D[%, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None]
```

I tried writing them all over the place. I always get a different error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer**

I had now little time to look at this again to see why `DSolve` gave series solution with `1/0` in it.  It turned put `DSolve` made a bug. The sum is correct, but it should be over odd $n$ only and not over all $n$. (Will send bug report to Wolfram support so that they can fix this in next version)

I also wrote the solution by hand to verify that this is the case. So now `DSolve` gives an exact solution for all $n$ when the sum is manually fixed to be over odd numbers also.

### Comparing Fixed DSolve solution with NDSolve

You can obtain direct solution using `DSolve`.

The trick is the boundary conditions. `DSolve` has hard time with it starting at not $x=0$. Therefore do a mapping by solving for $z=x+\pi$. This transfers the BC from $-\pi \dots \pi$ to $0 \dots 2\pi$ and now `DSolve` can indeed solve the PDE exactly.

At the end just replace $z$ back by $x+\pi$.

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, n, z];
pde = D[u[z, t], {t, 2}] == 4*D[u[z, t], {z, 2}];
ic = {u[z, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][z, 0] == (Sin[z])^2};
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[2 Pi, t] == 0}; (*notice the shift*)
sol = First@(u[z, t] /. DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[z, t], {z, t}]);
sol = sol /. {K[1] -> n, z -> x + Pi}(*reset the spatial shift*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above solution is correct, but sum should be over odd $n$ only. Fixed by hand

```
MMfixedSolution[x_, t_, max_] := 
 Sum[(16 (-1 + (-1)^n) Sin[n t] Sin[1/2 n(Pi + x)])/(n^2 (-16 + n^2)Pi),{n,1, max, 2}]
```

The above is the final exact solution. Let us now compare the above solution (using few terms in the Fourier series) with the numerical solution posted above by Henrik Schumacher and plot them one top of each.

```
ClearAll[u, x, t, n];
weqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 4*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Sin[x]^2};
bc = {u[-Pi, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0};
solN = NDSolveValue[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 4}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.01, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 100}}}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{solN[x, t], MMfixedSolution[x, t, 5]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Numerical", "DSolve solution fixed"}],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 4, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Can't even spot the difference now between the numerical and the exact, and this is only using 1,3,5 (i.e. 3 terms only) in the sum !

### Verification of `DSolve` solution by hand

Solving for $t>0,-\pi<x<\pi$
$$
u_{tt}=c^{2}u_{xx}
$$
With BC
\begin{align*}
u\left(  -\pi,t\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  \pi,t\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}
And initial conditions
\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =0\\
u_{t}\left(  x,0\right)   &  =\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}

Let $\xi=x+\pi$. When $x=-\pi,\xi=0$ and when $x=\pi,\xi=2\pi$. In terms of
$\xi$, the new pde in $U\left(  \xi,t\right)  $ becomes

$$
U_{tt}=c^{2}U_{\xi\xi}
$$
With BC
\begin{align*}
U\left(  0,t\right)   &  =0\\
U\left(  2\pi,t\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}
And initial conditions
\begin{align*}
U\left(  \xi,0\right)   &  =0\\
U_{t}\left(  \xi,0\right)   &  =\sin^{2}\left(  \xi\right)
\end{align*}

Let $U=X\left(  \xi\right)  T\left(  t\right)  $. The PDE\ becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{T^{\prime\prime}X}{c^{2}} &  =X^{\prime\prime}T\\
\frac{1}{c^{2}}\frac{T^{\prime\prime}}{T} &  =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}
{X}=-\lambda
\end{align*}
Where $\lambda$ is separation constant. Hence the eigenvalue ODE\ is
\begin{align*}
X^{\prime\prime}+\lambda X &  =0\\
X\left(  0\right)   &  =0\\
X\left(  2\pi\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}
From the boundary conditions, we see that $\lambda>0$ is the only possible
value. Therefore the solution to the above ODE\ is
$$
X\left(  x\right)  =A\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}\xi\right)  +B\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}\xi\right)
$$
Since $X\left(  0\right)  =0$ then $A=0$ and the solution becomes $X\left(
\xi\right)  =B\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}\xi\right)  $. Since $X\left(
2\pi\right)  =0$ then for non trivial solution we want $\sqrt{\lambda}
2\pi=n\pi$ or
$$
\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n}{2}\right)  ^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
Hence the eigenfunctions are
$$
X_{n}\left(  \xi\right)  =\sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\xi\right)  \qquad
n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
The time ODE now becomes
\begin{align*}
T_{n}^{\prime\prime}+c^{2}\lambda_{n}T_{n}  & =0\\
T_{n}^{\prime\prime}+c^{2}\left(  \frac{n}{2}\right)  ^{2}T_{n}  & =0\\
T_{n}^{\prime\prime}+\frac{c^{2}n^{2}}{4}T_{n}  & =0
\end{align*}
Which has the solution
$$
T_{n}\left(  t\right)  =D_{n}\cos\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)  +E_{n}
\sin\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)
$$
Therefore the complete solution becomes
\begin{equation}
U\left(  \xi,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}\cos\left(  \frac
{cn}{2}t\right)  +E_{n}\sin\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)  \right)  \sin\left(
\frac{n}{2}\xi\right)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Switching back to $x$ the above becomes

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}\cos\left(  \frac{cn}
{2}t\right)  +E_{n}\sin\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)  \right)  \sin\left(
\frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)  \tag{1A}
\end{equation}

At $t=0$ the above becomes
\begin{align*}
0  & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}\sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)
\right)  \\
D_{n}  & =0
\end{align*}

The solution (1A) simplifies to

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\sin\left(  \frac{cn}
{2}t\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Taking time derivative of (2) gives
$$
u_{t}\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  E_{n}\frac{cn}{2}
\cos\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(
x+\pi\right)  \right)
$$
At $t=0$ the above becomes
$$
\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\frac{cn}{2}\sin\left(
\frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)
$$
Applying orthogonality gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(
x+\pi\right)  \right)  dx &  =E_{n}\frac{cn}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin
^{2}\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)  dx\\
&  =E_{n}\frac{\pi cn}{2}
\end{align*}

For the LHS, for $n$ even $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)  dx=0$. Hence $E_{n}=0$
for all $n$ even. For $n$ odd
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(
x+\pi\right)  \right)  dx  & =\frac{16\left(  \cos\left(  n\pi\right)
-1\right)  }{\left(  n^{2}-16\right)  n}\\
& =\frac{16\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  }{\left(  n^{2}
-16\right)  n}
\end{align*}

But $n$ is odd, hence the above simplifies more to

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}{2}\left(
x+\pi\right)  \right)  dx=\frac{-32}{\left(  n^{2}-16\right)  n}
$$

Therefore
\begin{align}
E_{n}  & =\frac{2}{n\pi c}\frac{-32}{\left(  n^{2}-16\right)  n}\nonumber\\
& =\frac{-64}{n^{2}\pi c\left(  n^{2}-16\right)  }\nonumber
\end{align}

Therefore the final solution (2) now becomes
$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\frac{-64}{n^{2}\pi
c\left(  n^{2}-16\right)  }\sin\left(  \frac{cn}{2}t\right)  \sin\left(
\frac{n}{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)
$$

Since $c=2$ then

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\frac{-32}{n^{2}\pi
 \left(  n^{2}-16\right)  }\sin\left(  nt\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n}
{2}\left(  x+\pi\right)  \right)
$$

Which is same as `DSolve` but sum should be over odd $n$.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try `NDSolveValue` instead with the following syntax:

```
weqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 4*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == (Sin[x])^2};
bc = {u[-Pi, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 4},
   MaxStepSize -> 0.01,
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 100}}}
   ];
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming symmetric solution `u[x,t]==u[-x,t]` (particulary `Derivative[1,0][u][0,t]`) you might, alternatively to @HenrikSchumacher 's  answer, use `"FiniteElement"`

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{weqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 4}, Method ->{"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}} ];
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 4}, Mesh -> None,AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}]
```

[image]